# No module named 'plotnine' error - despite successful installation of package to virtual environment

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtual, environment, plotnine

I have pip installed plotline version 0.8.0 to my conda environment and can see it listed when I type 'pip list' with all the other installed packages.
However, when I run 'import plotnine as p9' in my python script (using VS code application) I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plotnine'

Any idea why this is happening? Import of all other packages also in this environment works completely fine.

Comment: can you do `pip --version` and `python --version` to see if you have the matching versions ?

Comment: Make sure the PYTHONPATH in your VScode points to your conda environment's directory where plotline is installed. Do you get import errors for other packages?

Comment: Hi @Steven pip --version comes says python 3.9 and python --version says 2.7.16. Would you know how I can update the python version?

Comment: Hi @darthbaba , yes my VScode does definitely point to the correct conda environment and no I don't get import errors for any other packages, just this one!

Comment: Python 2.7.16? Are you on Macos?

Comment: You have Python 3.9 somewhere on your system. That means that you'll have to tell VS Code to use that Python, somewhere in its settings.

Comment: The fact that other packages work with your default VS Code environment, probably means you have installed those packages for another Python version. That may be because you installed a new Python version later, or a new pip version, and things got out of sync. In fact, if you set VS Code to use the Python version that has plotnine installed, there is a chance you'll find other packages missing, and you'll have to reinstall those.

Comment: On Macos, you can use `Command + ,` to get to the settings, then search for `python interpreter` in the search bar, then select Python in the listing. If that all works, you should be able to enter a "Default Interpreter Path" that points to the actual Python you'll want to use.

Comment: You mention VS Code points to the correct Conda environment (how, though?). In that case, find the corresponding Python interpreter for that environment, and try and run `python -m pip install plotnine` instead. That guarantees you that the pip version you used corresponds to the Python version you used (just be aware that you use the correct Python version. Not 2.7.16, that's bad).

Comment: @9769953 Thank you for your comments. I know VScode points to the correct environment because at the bottom left of the VScode window is says "Python 3.8.5 64-bit ('env':venv)"... it is odd that is says 3.8.5 here because when I open terminal on VScode, cd to 'env' (my virtual environment) folder and type in python --version its says 'Python 2.7.16', however if I open a terminal window outside of VScode and cd to 'env', and type python --version it says 'Python 3.8.5'.

Comment: @9769953 Also, my python path and default interpreter path on VScode both link to python3, so I am confused... and also confused as to how within VScode terminal the env python version is stated as 2.7.16, but when I open the env folder in finder and in terminal on mac it states python version3. Have quit and re-opened VScode with no change

Comment: Try with `python3` in the terminal. See if that's at least the one that VSCode uses.

Comment: @9769953 I think I have worked out the issue. When I type Command+Shift+P and then SelectInterpreter, I see the "Python 3.8.5 64-bit ('env':venv)" I see './env/bin/python' underneath it, but it should be './env/bin/python3' - do you know how I change that?